# Music and Sound Effects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to separate on and off(i mean how to mute separate ) function of Music Background and Sound Effect

**AudioManager**

```
public Sound[] sounds;

public static AudioManager instance;

void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = this;
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }

    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    foreach (Sound s in sounds)
    {
        s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        s.source.clip = s.clip;

        s.source.volume = s.volume;
        s.source.loop = s.loop;
        s.source.mute = s.mute;
    }
}
```

**Sound.cs**

```
public string name;
public AudioClip clip;

[Range(0f, 1f)]
public float volume;

public bool loop;
public bool mute;

[HideInInspector]
public AudioSource source;
```

[This is my Music and Sound Effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9YLt.png)

Comment: I suggest you do this job use AudioMixer.

Comment: Can you give me more information? if I could get, you have some sounds in SoundManager and want to mute each sound separately.

Comment: That's right @EhsanMohammadi

Comment: I have Sound effect and Music Background.. and i want to mute this two audio separately

Comment: Shouldn't `sounds[0].source.mute= true` work?

Comment: @Programmer thankyou ! its work ;)

Comment: @CFPHElipsis Ok, I think you don't need to Sound.cs script. Add AudioSource to your game objects and use `AudioSource[] sounds` in AudioManager. and use `sounds[index].mute = true / false`